# How to make System command calls in Java/Groovy?

Tags: command-line, groovy, build-automation

What I want to do is invoke maven from a groovy script. The groovy script in question is used as a maven wrapper to build J2EE projects by downloading a tag and invoking maven on what was downloaded. How should I accomplish invoking maven to build/package the EAR (the groovy script is already capable of downloading the tag from SCM).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The simplest way to invoke an external process in Groovy is to use the execute() command on a string. For example, to execute maven from a groovy script run this:

```
"cmd /c mvn".execute()
```

If you want to capture the output of the command and maybe print it out, you can do this:

```
print "cmd /c mvn".execute().text
```

The 'cmd /c' at the start invokes the Windows command shell. Since mvn.bat is a batch script you need this. For Unix you can invoke the system shell.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know you can do that.

Comment: This worked first time for me. Went down the Process "consumeProcessOutput()" route for a while but had no dice with that.

This'll help greatly with determining reasons for Docker build fails.

Answer (score 35):

It is as simple as doing

```
"yourCommand".execute();
```

If you want to get print outputs on the executed command on standard output you can do

```
def proc = "yourCommand".execute();
proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
```

If you want to store and process the output you can do

```
def proc = "yourCommand".execute();
def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err);
println(outputStream.toString());
```

**UPDATE:**

Also you can set working dir by

```
File workingDir = file("<path to dir>")
def proc = "yourCommand".execute([], workingDir.absolutePath);
```

Comment: when I do this def homeDir = "c:/test/server";
def workDir = "${homeDir}/workDir";
def tempDir = "${workDir}/tmp";

println(homeDir);
println(workDir);
runShell("cd c:");
//runShell("mkdir -p ${tempDir}");


void runShell(String s) {

def execute = s.execute();
execute.waitForProcessOutput(System.out,System.err);
def value = execute.exitValue();
        if (val > 0) {
            throw new Exception("Exit value: ${value}");
        }
}
I get an error as below java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 6):

For Java 7+ stdio redirection:

```
new ProcessBuilder('cmd', …args…).redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT).start().waitFor();
```

Comment: If you pass in a `List` of args, make sure the elements are all `String`s and not [GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html)s with interpolated variables. Also don't forget to `redirectError` as well.

Answer (score 4):

You may use Runtime class to launch a shell command. take a look here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)
You may later capture the results of the Process execution (to find out if it failed or not).