# Execute shell script in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, cygwin

I have a gradle build setup at the beginning of which I want to execute a shellscript in a subdirectory that prepares my environment.

```
task build << {
}
task preBuild << {
    println 'do prebuild stuff:'
}
task myPrebuildTask(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$projectDir/mySubDir"
    commandLine './myScript.sh'
}

build.dependsOn preBuild
preBuild.dependsOn myPrebuildTask
```

However, when I execute the task either by calling `gradle myPrebuildTask` or by simply building the project, the following error occurs:

```
> A problem occurred starting process 'command './myScript.sh''
```

Unfortunately, thats all I get. 
I have also tried the following - same error.

```
commandLine 'sh mySubDir/myScript.sh'
```

I use Gradle 1.10 (needed by Android) on Windows, inside a Cygwin shell. Any ideas?

Answer (score 46):

use

```
commandLine 'sh', './myScript.sh'
```

your script itself is not a program itself, that's why you have to declare 'sh' as the program and the path to your script as an argument.

Comment: different commands for executing under linux and windows (Cygwin) are needed. I ended up supplying the scriptname as parameter: commandLine 'sh','myScript.sh'

Comment: Remember to put the task into the project gradle file and not the module gradle file.

Answer (score 46):

A more generic way of writing the exec task, but portable for Windows/Linux, if you are invoking a command file on the PATH:

```
task myPrebuildTask(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$projectDir/mySubDir"
    if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'mycommand'
    } else {
        commandLine 'sh', '-c', 'mycommand'
    }
}
```

This doesn't directly address the use case for the OP (since there is script file in the working directory), but the title of the question is more generic (and drew me here), so it could help someone maybe.

Answer (score 19):

unfortunately options with **commandLine** not worked for me in any way and my friend find other way with **executable**

```
executable "./myScript.sh"
```

and full task would be

```
task startScript() {
  doLast {
     exec {
          executable "./myScript.sh"
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This works for me in my Android project

```
preBuild.doFirst {
    println("Executing myScript")
    def proc = "mySubDir/myScript.sh".execute()
    proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
}
```

See here for explanation:
[How to make System command calls in Java/Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701547/how-to-make-system-command-calls-in-java-groovy)

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**) derived from [Charlie Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59260179/8583692):

```kotlin
task<Exec>("MyTask") {
    doLast {
        commandLine("git")
            .args("rev-parse", "--verify", "--short", "HEAD")
            .workingDir(rootProject.projectDir)
    }
}
```

Another approach using the Java standard *ProcessBuilder* API:

```kotlin
tasks.create("MyTask") {
    val command = "git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD"
    doLast {
        val process = ProcessBuilder()
            .command(command.split(" "))
            .directory(rootProject.projectDir)
            .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
            .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT)
            .start()
        process.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        val result = process.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
        println(result)
    }
}
```

For more information see:

- [How to run a command line command with Kotlin DSL in Gradle 6.1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60061168/8583692)
- [How to invoke external command from within Kotlin code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35421699/8583692)

Answer (score 2):

for kotlin gradle you can use

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./my_script.sh")
```

Answer (score -10):

I copied my shell scipt to `/usr/local/bin` with `+x` permission and used it as just another command:

```
commandLine 'my_script.sh'
```

Comment: This option works to, but i dont recomend put many files in /usr/local/bin

Comment: You sure you don't want to delete this answer?

Comment: If I delete, one wouldn't know how not to do it. Plus, it did work for me.

Comment: While the suggested action "works" it doesn't allow for the project to be portable and will require manual steps from anyone who needs to run the gradle build for the project.

Comment: @JoeyG I guess this can stay here. It is downvoted enough to give anyone seeking answer a hint that this recipe should be taken with caution :)