# How to check if current Android apk is generated from provided git commit?

Tags: android, git, version-control, google-play

As service provider, I want to verify whether the client have published the same git commit apk, which I have reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not being recorded during apk bundling, I believe it would be impossible to fetch. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35041457/3138726) answer to get an idea of how to include a git hash.

Then there are two options
- Either feed that data up in some kind of Analytics (Preferred)
- Or you can go ahead and decompile your apk and hunt through the files.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can easily check is build the APK yourself from the git commit, then check for code identity, maybe looking at the hash of the classes.dex files in the APK.