# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found for custom method

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm having an issue adding a custom method in my build.gradle file to retrieve the git branch and commit hash. Here's my code:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***.***.***"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_HASH", getGitHash()
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_BRANCH", getGitBranch()
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    def getGitHash = { ->
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        return "\"" + stdout.toString().trim() + "\""
    }

    def getGitBranch = { ->
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        return "\"" + stdout.toString().trim() + "\""
    }
}
```

The problem? Well I'm getting the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 0s
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'getGitHash()'
```

My gradle plug-in ver is 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the definitions for the methods `getGitHash` and `getGitBranch` are WITHIN the `android` section of the build.gradle file. Instead they need to be ABOVE the `android` section. Such as:

```
def getGitHash = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return "\"" + stdout.toString().trim() + "\""
}

def getGitBranch = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return "\"" + stdout.toString().trim() + "\""
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***.***.***"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_HASH", getGitHash()
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_BRANCH", getGitBranch()
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Doing this has fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

The custom method "getGitHash()" defined in gradle is only available in this gradle file.
Please check if you calling it from somewhere outside.
Also you need to define the method before you use it, i.e place it above in your code.

Comment: I'm not using it outside of my gradle file. In fact my implementation is very similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35041457/10952276. Even following that answer exactly yields the same error. And what specifically do you mean by place it above in my code? Trying to access the values from the BuildConfig isn't possible until I'm able to sync my project. Which is what this error is preventing

Comment: I fixed the issue in my answer below

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i meant. Putting the function definition ABOVE, in your code.  i.e define the function before you use it, put it above the android section