# Gradle Kotlin DSL can't find java.io package

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to convert the build.gradle file of an Android app to a Kotlin DSL.
This file has a function like this:

```
def getLastCommitHash() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

which I converted to this:

```
fun getLastCommitHash() {
    val stdout = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine("git", "rev-parse", "--short", "HEAD")
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

I get an `Unresolved reference: ByteArrayOutputStream` error and applying the import which changes it to `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()` shows an `Unresolved reference: io` error.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran into the same issue after finding a nearly identical function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35041457) and converting it. Upvoted for asking the exact question I had.

Comment: in gradle/kotlin the java value is shadowing the package name, making it nigh impossible to import anything from `java.*`

The answer to this question will answer "how do you reference the java package name while it's being shadowed by a variable in kotlin?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with Android Studio 3.5.6. After upgrading to Android Studio 3.6 everything is working.

Comment: I have this issue and it's not using Android Studio but IntelliJ.

Answer (score 10):

Importing from `java.io` works when doing it *before* the `plugins` block. I could successfully run builds for both Gradle 7.3.2 and 6.9.2 with the following `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

plugins {
    `java-library`
}

println(ByteArrayOutputStream::class)
```

If you [escape](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/syntax-and-grammar.html#identifiers) the full package name, then you can also make it work without importing the class (tested as above):

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
}

println(`java.security`.MessageDigest::class)
```

Comment: Something strange was happening for me initially, in that IntelliJ seemed reluctant to add imports to a build.gradle.kts, and that it was highlighting the import with a warning.

Granted I can't seem to reproduce it now. (my issue was with java.security.MessageDigest)

This was the solution I had ended up coming to as well, but it still left me wondering if there was any way of escaping the shadowing when referring to the long name.

Comment: I believe I’ve found a way, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue in backend project in intellij idea, I added this import at the top of `build.gradle` file:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
```

And now it works.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for build.gradle.kts aka KOTLIN like the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

My observation:

- close project
- delete `.idea` and `.gradle` folders
- open project by selecting root-`build.gradle.kts` with "open as project"

did help.