# How to run a command line command with Kotlin DSL in Gradle 6.1.1?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-task

I am trying to run the code block below, after reading multiple posts on the topic and the Gradle manual. I run the below and get the following error: execCommand == null!

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong with the below code block?

```kotlin
open class BuildDataClassFromAvro : org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec() {

    @TaskAction
    fun build() {
        println("Building data classes.....")
        commandLine("date")
    }
}

tasks.register<BuildDataClassFromAvro>("buildFromAvro") {
    description = "Do stuff"
}
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to get the task to do? An `Exec` task is for running a cmd-line process, so you don't need to actually create a Kotlin class that subclasses it: instead you create a Gradle task of type `Exec` and define the `commandLine` in there (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html). Are you trying to run a cmd-line process? Or are you trying to write a task that will run some custom Kotlin code?

Comment: I am trying to run a command line process as part of the build process.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To define a Gradle task that runs a command-line using the Gradle Kotlin DSL do something like this in your build file:

```
task<Exec>("buildFromAvro") {
    commandLine("echo", "test")
}
```

In the example above the `commandLine` will simply run `echo`, outputting the value `test`. So replace that with whatever you want to actually do.

You can then run that with `gradle buildFromAvro`

More info here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Comment: I keep getting too many characters in a character literal 'echo'

Comment: @FilBot3 If you're getting that error, you're probably using `'` instead of `"` - single quotes instead of double. They have different meanings.

Comment: This command doesn't do anything in 2023 :(

Comment: @Kofi If you are running as part of the Android Studio build process it is not working, but it is when run from the terminal with `gradlew buildFromAvro`, reasons unknown

Answer (score 2):

If adding to an existing task:

```
exec {
    commandLine("echo", "hi")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the [Java ProcessBuilder API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```kotlin
tasks.create("MyTask") {
    val command = "echo Hello"
    doLast {
        val process = ProcessBuilder()
            .command(command.split(" "))
            .directory(rootProject.projectDir)
            .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
            .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT)
            .start()
            .waitFor(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        val result = process.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
        println(result) // Prints Hello
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope didactique code to execute the ls command against workingDir.

```kotlin
    @Throws(RuntimeException::class)
    fun Project.lsWorkingDir() = ByteArrayOutputStream().use { outputStream ->
        exec {
            standardOutput = outputStream
            workingDir = projectDir
            when {
                "os.name"
                    .run(System::getProperty)
                    .lowercase()
                    .contains("windows") -> commandLine("cmd.exe", "/c", "dir", workingDir, "/b")

                else -> commandLine("ls", workingDir)
            }
        }.let { result ->
            when {
                result.exitValue != 0 -> throw RuntimeException("Command ls failed.")
                else -> outputStream.toString()
                    .trim()
                    .let { "Command ls output:\n$it" }
                    .let(::println)
            }
        }
    }



tasks.register("lsWorkingDir") {
    group = "playground"
    description = "Run ls command against workingDir."
    doFirst { lsWorkingDir() }
}
```