# Unable to Run `gradle` related commands in loop within bash script

Tags: bash, shell, gradle, command-line

I've written a `shell-script` to build all projects mentioned in a particular file using a `while` loop and `gradle clean build` command to do so.

Here is how it looks like:

```
echo -e "\Building all projects"
filename="projects"      #File Containing all projects name to build
workdir=$(pwd)
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    echo -e "\ngradle build repo - $name"
    cd $workdir/$name
    gradle clean build 
done < "$filename"
```

Here is contents of projects file:

```
core
dal
dao
web
ui
```

and here is my directory structure

```
src
|-script.sh
|-core
|  |-build.gradle
|  |-gradle.properties
|  |-src
|  |-otherstuff
|
|-dal
|  |-build.gradle
|  |-gradle.properties
|  |-src
|  |-otherstuff
|
|-dao
|  |-build.gradle
|  |-gradle.properties
|  |-src
|  |-otherstuff
|
|-same repeats for web and ui
```

So I expect my script to read file `projects` and go into all the mentioned `folders` from that file and issue command `gradle clean build` in that folder.

Everything works fine and as expected except `gradle` command no matter whether build succeeds or fails for the first project (`core`) it makes script to break the loop and exit.

So It prints output only for the first project and doesn't work for all other.

However,

If I try to run it in the background it works fine; ie;
instead of

```
gradle clean build
```

if I issue

```
gradle clean build &
```

It works fine; Although output, in that case, is gibberish.

Can anyone please look into this and help me out??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about doing this the other way around?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562207/execute-shell-script-in-gradle

Comment: try forcing the return value of gradle to success: `gradle clean build || true`; however, most build system try to do it the other way round: stop early when a built-error appears...

Comment: @umläute, Already tried it; also tried to catch return value in `if` but with no luck :( . Also even if the `gradle build` runs without any error still it stops after the first iteration itself.. Don't know what is happening internally.

Comment: try `gradle --console plain clean build & disown`

Comment: @MichaelJaros, Thanks For suggestion but it didn't helped as output is still gibberrish..

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, issuing `gradle --console plain clean build </dev/null` solved my issue :) !