# Android AIDL - generate headers + implementation for native code (android NDK)

Tags: android, android-ndk, aidl

Is there a way to have gradle generate the headers + implementation of an AIDL file for native code (android NDK)? I followed the instructions here (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) but this only generates code for java/kotlin code.  It doesn't generate anything for native code (c++).

I was able to generate the headers + implementation manually using the "aidl" tool as described here (https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/aidl/aidl-backends) but I was hoping there was a way to do this through gradle so that this is taken care of for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Put your commands to script (run "aidl" tool) and run it like prebuilt task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562207/execute-shell-script-in-gradle

Comment: Thanks @NikolayKhilyuk, this is the solution I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mykola mentioned in comments, we can have a prebuild Gradle task.

File structure of the Android Gradle module (project) :

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── aidl
│   │   │   ├── com
│   │   │   │   ├── example
│   │   │   │   │   ├── IMyService.aidl
├── build.gradle.kts
```

`IMyService.aidl`

```java
package com.example;
interface IMyService {
    // Function declarations of the interface come here...
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
}

android {
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 34
    }
}

tasks.create("compileAidlNdk") {
    doLast {
        // Path to aidl tool
        val aidl = arrayOf<String>(
            project.android.sdkDirectory.absolutePath,
            "build-tools", project.android.buildToolsVersion, "aidl"
        ).joinToString(File.separator)

        val outDir = arrayOf<String>(
            project.projectDir.absolutePath, "src", "main", "cpp", "aidl"
        ).joinToString(File.separator)

        val headerOutDir = arrayOf<String>(
            project.projectDir.absolutePath, "src", "main", "cpp", "includes"
        ).joinToString(File.separator)

        val searchPathForImports = arrayOf<String>(
            project.projectDir.absolutePath, "src", "main", "aidl"
        ).joinToString(File.separator)

        val aidlFile = arrayOf<String>(
            project.projectDir.absolutePath, "src", "main", "aidl",
            "com", "example", "IMyService.aidl"
        ).joinToString(File.separator)

        // Exec aidl command to generate headers and source files for IMyService.aidl
        ProcessBuilder(aidl,
            "--lang=ndk",
            "-o", outDir,
            "-h", headerOutDir,
            "-I", searchPathForImports,
            aidlFile
        ).start().waitFor()
    }
}

// To generate headers and source files for IMyService.aidl before each build
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.named("preBuild") {
        dependsOn(tasks.named("compileAidlNdk"))
    }
}
```